# SharePoint 2013 when adding Library on page unable to see New, Upload, Sync, edit etc option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, document

I've created document library in SharePoint 2013. After creating document library if I'm directly accessing the document library I'm able to see New, Upload, Sync, Edit other option provided by SharePoint 2013.

However if same document library If I'm adding on page its showing very less option even I tried to change created document library web part from edit option. Please advice.

[image]

Comment: Have you set Show Toolbar in library webpart and select your current view in View's settings of library webpart

Comment: Yes I selected but its not showing new,upload,sync,edit, search etc options. Please advice